# Remove group memberships from users who are disabled

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to write a script to find disabled users that is member of one or more groups in a specific OU in AD. It will then remove all the groups for all the disabled users. But I want to generate a list of users, with the exception of a list of names. Lets say I dont want to remove groups for some specific disabled users.

```
$SearchBase = "OU=Disabled Users,DC=contoso,DC=com"
$Users = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties MemberOf
$ExcludeUsers =@("SM_82786dfdc96642ed9","SM_516a93b689334db1a")
$Users = $Users | where-Object { $ExcludeUsers -notcontains $_.samaccountname }
ForEach($User in $Users){
$User.MemberOf | Remove-ADGroupMember -Member $User -Confirm:$false
}
```

Error:

```
Remove-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
At line:3 char:22
+     $User.MemberOf | Remove-ADGroupMember -Member $User -Confirm:$false
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADGroupMember
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you found a user without any groups (Domain Users is not part of `memberof`). Use something like `Where-Object` to filter out null-objects. Ex:

```
$User.MemberOf | Where-Object { $_ } | Remove-ADGroupMember -Member $User -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: Nothing happends? So no more error? `Remove-ADGroupMember` doesn't output results... check the users memberships (using `Get-ADUser` or AD console.. `$user.memberof` will still have old values)

Comment: I have checked the user.  I can still see group members of user